# Is 不 A 不 B a grammatical structure like 又 A 又 B?

Tags: grammar, idioms

I ran across 不知不觉 the other day.  If I use MDBG to look up `c:不*不*` I see there are many idioms with that format.  Can I use it with any verbs (?) or is it only part of fixed expressions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is 不 A 不 B a grammatical structure like 又 A 又 B?

They are different. Most [不 A 不 B] terms are either idiom or four characters idiomatic phrase that you have to memorize individually.

The A and B in [又 A 又 B] can be a single character word, a compound word or even an entire phrase. e.g. 又高又瘦，又高又瘦削，又想高大又想瘦削

Below are the common [不 A 不 B] terms:

[A complement B ]

不慌不忙: (not panic, not hurry) **stay calm**

不聞不問: (not listening, not inquire) **ignore**

不知不覺: (not know, not feel) **not notice**

不經不覺: (not experience, not feel) **not notice** (of time passing)

不瞅不睬: (not looking, not pay attention) **ignore**

不明不白: (not understandable, not clear) **unclear**

不倫不類: (not any type or kind) **ridiculous**

不慍不火: (not angry, not enrage) **calm; mild**

不痛不癢: (not hurt, not itchy) **insignificant attack/ lost**

不飲不食: (not eat, not drink) **not eat nor drink**

不眠不休: (not sleep, not rest) **tirelessly;  relentlessly, persistently**

不忠不孝: **disloyal**, **not filial** (no virtue)

不仁不義: **unkind, unjust** (no honor)

不過不失: (not considered a wrong doing, not considered a mistake) **average/ mediocre**

不折不扣: (no discount, no rebate) **truly**; **definitely**

不離不棄: (not leaving, not abandon) **never abandon**

不盡不實: (not detailed, not true) **not telling the truth**

不驕不躁: (not prideful, not irritated) **stay calm and focused**

不屈不撓: (not bending, not yielding) **Never give up**

不三不四: (not this, not that) **dubious**

不依不饒: (not agree with, not forgive) **pestering/ not let things go**

不聲不響: (Silent, not make a sound) **silently/ be silent**

[A contradict B ]

不卑不亢: (not too humble, not too excited) **proper demeanor**

不偏不倚: (not lend away , not lean onto) **right on**/ **Objective** (opinion)

不緩不迭: (not slow, not swift) **steady normal pace**

不男不女: (not a man, nor a woman) **sex unknown**

不上不下: (not up, not down) **struct in the middle**

不大不小: (not big, not small) **the right size**

不冷不熱: (not hot not cold) **mild reception**; **right temperature**

不高不低; (not high, not low) **middle position** (of rank or level)

不胖不瘦: (not fat, not thin) **average body type**

不咸不淡: (not salty not bland) **unremarkable taste/ mediocre**

[B until/ unless A]

不死不休: **not stopping until one is dead**

不吐不快: **not happy until saying (something)**

不時不食: **do not eat unless it is in-season**

不見不散: **not leaving until we meet**

*I would update this list when I think up more.*

Comment: Great list, thanks for the reference @TangHo

Answer (score 6):

why not? see bkrs: II cons.
1) 不 A 不 B (where A B are paired synonyms): not A B
不慌不忙 unhurried
2) 不 A 不 B (where A B are antonymous stative verbs): neither A nor B
不大不小 neither (too) big nor (too) small
3) 不 A 不 B (where A B are antonymous verbs): no B without A
不破不立 no constructing without destroying
cf. restrictions for  又 。。。又, see e.g. https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22both_A_and_B%22_with_%22you%22 bkrs:又.... 又…  linking antonyms, often translated as neither... nor, 又不好, 又不坏 , 又不哭, 又不笑,
[又]不是牛又不是马

Answer (score 2):

No,  not with **any** verb, although you would see lots of  idioms follow that pattern. You need to learn them separately.

Comment: editing suggestion: 2 adjectives, 2 verbs